# per appengine SDK 1.7.6, connecting to backend now fails

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an android app with a GAE backend.  I deploy the backend, and I used to be able to store entities in the datastore.  However after the recent 1.7.6 sdk update, I can no longer do so.  Connecting to the service, used to be https://1.myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/, however that now generates a unverified error.  I tried changing it to https://-1-myapp.appspot.com like the documentation said, however that just generates a 404 error.  Anyway around this?

Comment: Try `https://1-myapp.appspot.com`

Comment: thanks that worked.  What should the new url for the endpoint classes be?  Right now https://1-myapp.appspot.com/myclassendpoint/v1/myclass is getting a 404 too.